# How to hide button after user makes registration successfully?

Tags: android, authentication, hide, registration, preferences

I have a Login activity in which user can log in or press on Register button.
If he clicks on register button a Registration activity is open and he can send new registration to my site. After registration the Registration activity is closed and the user cames back to Login activity in which now i want to hide the register button.
How to do that?

I put this code in **Login.java** after user make the login successfully:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("STATUS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("username", username);
    editor.putBoolean("isLogged", true);
    editor.commit();
```

This is the code i add in **Main.java** to hide Login button (that throws Login activity) if the user is logged in:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("STATUS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean p = prefs.getBoolean("isLogged", false);

    if (p) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.Login);
        item.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Then i add this code to **Registration.java** after user make the registration successfully:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("STATUS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isRegistered", true);
    editor.commit();
```

Now how to edit again Login.java to check if the user already make the registration and then hide the registration button?

Comment: `boolean p = prefs.getBoolean("isRegistered", false);`

Comment: item.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: @PedroOliveira i get this error "prefs cannot be resolved" because i put your code in another method in which prefs is not initialized. Have i to inizialize it twice in Login.java?

Comment: @user3347882 i know it, thank you anyway for your comment

Comment: You have to initilize sharePreferences everytime

Comment: Done, but it doesn't work... `isRegistered` is always false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check as

```
 SharedPreferences  prefs = getSharedPreferences("STATUS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isRegistered = prefs.getBoolean("isRegistered", false);
```

then hide register as

```
  if (isRegistered ) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.Registration);
        item.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Note : change `R.id.Registration` with your registration button id.

Comment: prefs cannot be resolved. I get this error because i put your code in another method in which `prefs` is not initialized. Have i to inizialize it twice in Login.java?

Comment: @smartmouse in which file,Main.java or login.java as you are hiding login button in main file.

Comment: I told you, in Login.java

Comment: @smartmouse then again initialize it.see edited answer.

Comment: @smartmouse did you clear your project before retry.And is your user registered?

Comment: Yes, i tried to fill the form and send the registration, then it throws again Login and it says always false (i see it with Log.e)

Comment: Translation matter :P I had to translate in english some words of the code before paste here and then when i copied your code i forgot to re-translate in my language

Comment: It works but i have to throws again Login from Registration. If i put finish() then how to update previous activity (Login)?

Comment: @smartmouse what do you want exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63114/discussion-between-smartmouse-and-giru-bhai).

Answer (score 0):

```
item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

is what you need

Comment: You misunderstand me. Thank you anyway